# Firefox pops up when you clear downloads

Tags: firefox-for-android

I've ran into this problem for years. I download a bunch of pics in Firefox, and then have to manually clear the download list. When I do, Firefox is brought to the foreground.

This should not be the case, and I think it's a bug.

I can't find anything about this, possibly because the search terms are too common.

Are there fixes or mitigations for this behavior?

Currently running rooted on android 5.1 on Note 2, but this problem has occured on different devices and different versions of Android. I think 4.x and later. That's coincidental though, because Firefox only really got official about that same time.

Comment: Do you have the latest Firefox version? If it's a bug (and you're probably right there), it's a bug in Firefox.

Comment: Yes, at periods of time over the past few years, I have indeed had "the latest" version of Firefox.

Comment: I tested on Marshmallow on my device- Moto X Play. It doesn't happen. I funny see Firefox popping up when I delete downloads